# How to check cookies on subsequent request in asp.net mvc core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am basically looking for a way and place to check cookies on subsequent requests by the user. How will I check the user cookie when the user comeback to the same website.

This is the process.
in First time

1. User login in with userid and password
2. cookie is set on the browser which has encrypted (sessionid and userid)

Now my question is when the user next time come to the website again and his cookie will be available in the browser. What process will i follow to re set isvalidated property without login

1. will I check that the cookie exists and revalidate session id in database in login page or mainlayout and set isvalidated?
2. basically what will be the process for revalidating user's cookie and setting isvalidated property?
3. how will i restrict no of database hits to database in this regards

Answer (score 0):

You should ask one question at a  time.

1. will I check that the cookie exists and revalidate session id in database in login page or mainlayout and set isvalidated =>
   Request.Cookies collection contains cookies received from the client
   To check for the existence of a cookie do as:-

   if(Request.Cookies["userid"] != null)

   cookie = Request.Cookies["userid"];
2. basically what will be the process for revalidating user's cookie and setting isvalidated property? => Need more info
3. how will i restrict no of database hits to database in this regards => If cookie exists extract info from it and dont make DB call.

@maztt pls mark as answer if it helped you.